# render a template and Keep running another background task in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would line to run a function without interrupting the current function as follows

```
def taskone(request):
    #processes of task one
    tasktwo()
    return render(request,"index.html")
```

As `taskone` executes, `tasktwo` should also start executing. Task one should allow task two to continue executing in the background as it renders the html page.

Please someone give me an idea on how to go about it.

Comment: This is generally done using something like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the [django-after-response](https://pypi.org/project/django-after-response/). This is much easier to set up than celery also less process-heavy. Only use celery if you need something complex like scheduling tasks, running multiple queues, etc.

The project does not have much documentation. You can find the docs in git repo itself - https://github.com/defrex/django-after-response

Comment: The provided library has no documentation at all. How is it even used?

Comment: @Hammad The project is quite simple and does not have a lot of documentation. Please find the documentation in Git repo itself - https://github.com/defrex/django-after-response